# String Format Returns Unexpected Results

Tags: c#, string, formatting, string-interpolation

I have a simple class that contains a property `Format` which is set to any given format specifier. I then use the property of this class to, as the name suggest, format the string.

Take the following example:

```
public class FormatDefinition {
    public string Format { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {

        var formatDefinition = new FormatDefinition {
            Format = "N"
        };

        var number = 20.5;

        var formatOne = string.Format("{0:" + formatDefinition.Format + "}", number);
        var formatTwo = string.Format("{0:formatDefinition.Format}", number);
        var formatThree = $"{number:formatDefinition.Format}";

        Console.WriteLine(formatOne);       //  20.5
        Console.WriteLine(formatTwo);       //  formatDefinition21Format
        Console.WriteLine(formatThree);     //  formatDefinition21Format

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why `formatTwo` and `formatThree` have a result of `formatDefinition21Format`? It seems the period `.` is replaced by the formatted number.

Comment: You are specifying a [custom numeric format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) consisting of the string `"formatDefinition.Format"`. This is taken to mean *constant string "formatDefinition"* followed by the decimal point (and therefore the entire number goes here) followed by *constant string "Format"*. The number is rounded to zero decimal places because there are no digits specified after the decimal point. The string `formatDefinition.Format` is not interpreted as C# code.

Comment: c# doesn't do string interpolation at all prior C# 6, and even then you need  to tell the compiler it's what you want.

Comment: @blorgbeard this makes complete sense and is the clearest answer to me. thanks for your feedback. If you add it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Posted as answer (which it should have been in the first place, I gotta stop answering in comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying a [custom numeric format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) consisting of the string `"formatDefinition.Format"`.

This is taken to mean *constant string "formatDefinition"* followed by the decimal point (and therefore the entire number goes here) followed by *constant string "Format"*.

The number is rounded to zero decimal places because there are no digits specified after the decimal point.

The string `formatDefinition.Format` is not interpreted as C# code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierPt) for Custom Number Format Strings:

> For fixed-point format strings (that is, format strings that do not
>   contain scientific notation format characters), numbers are rounded to
>   as many decimal places as there are digit placeholders to the right of
>   the decimal point.

It's because you have a decimal point with no digit placeholders to its right. You're telling it to round the number to zero decimal places - in other words, round to the nearest whole number.

These are all functionally the same - all return `a22b`.

```
string.Format("{0:a.b}", 21.5);
string.Format("{0:a0b}", 21.5);
string.Format("{0:a0.b}", 21.5);
```

Here's a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qnSGTK).